# Can't find project type in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I added "ASP.NET and web development" to Visual Studio 2022 through VS installer, but when creating a new project, it does not bring web projects!
What should I do?

[image]
[image]

Reinstall VS 2022 And VS Installer

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you still need to download those packages -> when I check my vs installer, i have 0b ready to install

[image: Visual studio installer]

Answer (score 0):

I only installed "ASP.NET and web Development" in Visual Studio, but my project type still contains the Web project type.

[image]

[image]

These are the other configurations of "ASP.NET and web Development" in my Visual Studio Installer. You can refer to the missing options to check what is installed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you are missing none of these options, you can use Visual Studio Installer to repair Visual Studio or reinstall "ASP.NET and web Development" or Visual Studio